# Ideas for a windows desktop application

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application

I am starting to make my own apps and publishing them. The problem I face is that my apps are mainly for my purposes. What are some problems that you face while in windows? I need some desktop application ideas that are simple but helpful.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Rather than giving you a fish, I will humbly try and teach you how to fish:

1. Take a blank sheet of paper and write out as clearly as you can the problem that you want to tackle. Clarity is key because clarity of purpose gets your mind focused on what you are really trying to accomplish.
2. Think of at least 20 ideas and write them down on that once blank paper. Let your mind really flow and give up worrying about whether your ideas are practical or what other people will think about them.
3. Read over your list and determine which ones actually are good ideas. You might want to put the list away for a while and then take it out the next day to see if you still think those ideas pass whatever test you have for your ideas.

Lather, rinse, repeat.

Note that I don't necessarily know that I have a problem until you show me that I have a problem, and then show me how to fix it.  Personally I think computers are still too hard to use, and I'm a programmer.  Because my work life is so complex I like software and gadgets that are simple and elegant.  MP3 players existed long before the iPod came out, but the iPod was able to get the mix right.

http://hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Come-Up-with-Good-Ideas

Comment: Thank you, o wise programming sensei.

Comment: I totally agree with you on the point that software should be simple and elegant. I think now-s-days software is too bl**dy complex and rather than helping us it is for the most part making our life more miserable.